# canvas, move while shoot

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am building a small game to learn HTML5 canvas and I came across an issue which involves triggering multiple events at same time.

I have a rectangle object that can move up and down, and shoot. Problem is, when you press spacebar to shoot (while arrow up or down) is hold, the object will stop moving. How can I make it keep moving while pressing spacebar?

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector(`canvas`),
  ctx = canvas.getContext(`2d`),
  body = document.querySelector(`body`)

let shooter = {
  y: canvas.height / 2 - 25,
  height: 50,
  width: 20,
  shots: [],

  draw_shooter() {
    ctx.strokeRect(5, this.y, this.width, this.height)
  },

  move_shooter(e) {
    if (e.code === "ArrowUp")
      if (this.y - 6 > 0) this.y -= 6;
    if (e.code === "ArrowDown")
      if (this.y + this.height + 6 < canvas.height) this.y += 6;
  },

  shoot() {
    let shot = {
      x: 30,
      y: this.y + 20,

      draw() {
        //check if more, then kill in array
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 10)
        this.x += 5;
      }
    }

    this.shots.push(shot)
  }
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  shooter.draw_shooter()
  shooter.shots.map((shot) => shot.draw())

  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

update()

body.addEventListener(`keydown`, (e) => shooter.move_shooter(e))
body.addEventListener(`keypress`, (e) => shooter.shoot(e))
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="200" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Would be great if you provided the HTML and CSS as well, so that we could reproduce the entire game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it would be to record pressed keys and move the shooter on every `update` based on which keys are currently pressed:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector(`canvas`),
    ctx = canvas.getContext(`2d`),
    body = document.body;

let shooter = {
  y: canvas.height / 2 - 25,
  height: 50,
  width: 20,
  // Pressed keys will be stored here
  pressed_keys: [],
  shots: [],

  draw_shooter() {
    ctx.strokeRect(5, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  },

  move_shooter() {
    const up   = this.pressed_keys.includes("ArrowUp"),
          down = this.pressed_keys.includes("ArrowDown");
    // If both keys are pressed, do nothing
    if (up && down) { return; }
    if (up) { this.y = Math.max(0, this.y - 2); }
    if (down) { this.y = Math.min(canvas.height, this.y + 2); }
  },

  // Add key to the Array
  on_key_down(e) {
    this.pressed_keys.push(e.code);
  },

  // Remove key from the Array
  on_key_up(e) {
    this.pressed_keys = this.pressed_keys.filter(k => k !== e.code);
  },

  shoot() {
    let shot = {
      x: 30,
      y: this.y + 20,
      draw() {
        //check if more, then kill in array
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 10);
        this.x += 5;
      }
    }
    this.shots.push(shot);
  }
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  shooter.draw_shooter();
  shooter.shots.map((shot) => shot.draw());
  // Move shooter
  shooter.move_shooter();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();

body.addEventListener(`keydown`, (e) => shooter.on_key_down(e));
body.addEventListener(`keyup`, (e) => shooter.on_key_up(e));
body.addEventListener(`keypress`, (e) => shooter.shoot(e));
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="200" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```